# How to do exponential calculations with BigInteger as exponent?

Tags: java

I have a BigInteger 'X' and want to see if the following is true or not:
3^(X/2)=(-1) (mod X)

Methods that do exponential calculations such as Math.pow(3, X) do not accept BigInteger as a value of X so how do I do the calculation above?

Comment: Are you sure your equation is correct? The left part is always positive as it represents an exponential function with a positive base whereas the right one is always negative due to multiplication of an absolute value of `X` (which is always positive) and -1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigDecimal.pow()`

An example from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/bigdecimal_pow_mc.htm).

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.math.*;

public class BigDecimalDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create 2 BigDecimal Objects
      BigDecimal bg1, bg2;

      MathContext mc = new MathContext(4); // 4 precision

      bg1 = new BigDecimal("2.17");

      // apply pow method on bg1 using mc
      bg2 = bg1.pow(3, mc);

      String str = "The value of " + bg1 + " to the power of 3, rounded to " + bg2;

      // print bg2 value
      System.out.println( str );
   }
}
```